# JetBrains DataGrip set field value to now()

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm using DataGrip inside PhpStorm to access MySQL database. From time to time I need to update datetime fields with current time. For example TablePlus has the option to set field value to `now()` and on save it populates it with current datetime. It would be nice to have something similar on DataGrip as it is my primary database editor and it is really annoying setting time by hand.

Maybe someone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this at the moment. Here are 2 related feature requests on our tracker, please follow and vote: '[add NOW to datepicker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-12691)', '[using functions in table editor](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7422)'

Comment: Thanks for pointing already existed issues (feature requests). Maybe you know in what time frame they might be done? I can see that issues are quite old at a moment.

Comment: Unfortunately no ETA, since there are more important tasks and these do not look like very popular.